# How do you reset an `ST` instance in `StringTemplate4`?

Tags: stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

StringTemplate instances in version 3 had a `.reset()` method.

I am generating inside a `for/each` loop and want to reset the instance to its default state at the end of each loop.
I have searched the JavaDoc and can not find out how to reset an instance of `ST` to reuse it.

#### How do you reset an `ST` instance in `StringTemplate4`?

Comment: Also, this information is damn useful if you need it. Could any of the downvoters explain?

Comment: @foo - it was serial downvoting from some very small people from a meta spat, like a year ago, ignore it, I know I do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [This is here because this was a hard thing to find!](https://xkcd.com/979/)

> The `.reset()` method was removed and there is no direct documentation that hints to how to accomplish this in version 4.
>
> By digging into the source code I discovered that `.getInstanceOf()`
>   delivers a cached uninitialized copy of the template there is no need
>   to call `.reset()` on the instances anymore, just get a fresh cached
>   instance.

#### Relevant code from [STGroup.java](https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/master/src/org/stringtemplate/v4/STGroup.java) as of the time of this answer:

```java
/** The primary means of getting an instance of a template from this
 *  group. Names must be absolute, fully-qualified names like {@code /a/b}.
 */
public ST getInstanceOf(String name) {
    if ( name==null ) return null;
    if ( verbose ) System.out.println(getName()+".getInstanceOf("+name+")");
    if ( name.charAt(0)!='/' ) name = "/"+name;
    CompiledST c = lookupTemplate(name);
    if ( c!=null ) {
        return createStringTemplate(c);
    }
    return null;
}

/** Look up a fully-qualified name. */
public CompiledST lookupTemplate(String name) {
    if ( name.charAt(0)!='/' ) name = "/"+name;
    if ( verbose ) System.out.println(getName()+".lookupTemplate("+name+")");
    CompiledST code = rawGetTemplate(name);
    if ( code==NOT_FOUND_ST ) {
        if ( verbose ) System.out.println(name+" previously seen as not found");
        return null;
    }
    // try to load from disk and look up again
    if ( code==null ) code = load(name);
    if ( code==null ) code = lookupImportedTemplate(name);
    if ( code==null ) {
        if ( verbose ) System.out.println(name+" recorded not found");
        templates.put(name, NOT_FOUND_ST);
    }
    if ( verbose ) if ( code!=null ) System.out.println(getName()+".lookupTemplate("+name+") found");
    return code;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, DenverCoder9, for salvaging the wisdom of the ancients!